# Listen for changes on object update Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a form that updates an object directly like so

*component.html*

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.name" />
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.surname" />
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.age" />
```

*component.ts*

```
user = {
  name: null,
  surname: null,
  age: null
}
```

now in my component.html I have a save button that is in a child component

```
<app-save-btn [user]="user"></app-save-btn>
```

and in the `app-save-btn` component I am listening for changes using `OnChanges`

```
@Input() user: User;

userForCompare: User;

ngOnChanges() {
  if (!this.userForCompare) {
    this.userForCompare = {...this.user};
  }
  console.log(this.userForCompare, this.user);
}
```

now my issue is, I get the first console log of the two user objects, but as I update further fields I no longer get change updates..

now I know that I could create seperate variables to hold each value, but I have like 30 field items so I dont want to change my implementation to much...

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

`@Input` property will trigger **ngOnChanges** function only when the Input object is mutated.

In your example, input fields are mutating each single property in the same user object, the user object for the `@Input` always refers to the same object (even though its child property name, surename and age are mutated), so `ngOnChanges` will not be triggered.

Therefore, you have to make `this.user` in `component.ts` equals to a brand new user object whenever any input field is changed.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Good explanation of why the OP solution doesn't work! The proposed solution can easily be done using Reactive Form since it uses immutable data structure, providing a new data model without touching the original data model... subscribing to each `NgModelChange` by hand would be so boilerplate!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a `FormGroup` with [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) to manipulate your fields. Using `FormBuilder.group()` you can create a form containing each for the property of the `User` object... that way you would only need to pass `form.value` to your child component.

> Reactive form keeps the data model pure by providing it as an **immutable** data structure. Each time a change occurs to the form, the `FormControl` instance will not update the existing data model, it will return a new state (a new data model).
>   https://www.ibrahima-ndaw.com/blog/5-reasons-to-use-reactive-form/

Here is a live StackBlitz example using the code below:
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-60424523

**example.component.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input [formControlName]="'name'" />
  <input [formControlName]="'surname'" />
  <input [formControlName]="'age'" />
</form>
<app-save-btn [user]="form.value"></app-save-btn>
```

**example.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  user: User = {
    name: 'Initial name',
    surname: 'Initial surname',
    age: 99
  };

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group(this.user);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering, I am aware of reactive forms, I was wondering if there was a way around this though, I am trying to avoid a lot of get/set repetition that comes from individual fields